# Can this condition make changes to the complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm trying to find the complexity of this code:

```
int count =0;
for(int i= 1 ; i<=MAX_SIZE ; i*=2){
    for(int j = 1; j<=i*i ; j++){
        if(i%j==0){
            for(int k = 1 ; k<=j ; k++)
                count++;
        }
    }
}
cout<<count<<endl;
```

The outer loop is O(log(n))
The middle loop is O(n^2)
The inner loop is O(n), and here is why:
the inner loop execute O(j) which is i*i, that is correct.
But the condition will execute only if i%j == 0 and when this statement is true it means that j must be less or equal than i.
proof:

```
int count =0;
int count2 = 0;
for(int i= 1 ; i<=10000 ; i*=2){
    for(int j = 1; j<=i*i ; j++){
        if(i%j==0){
            if(i>=j)
            {
                count2++;
            }
            count++;
        }
    }
}
cout<<count<<endl;
cout<<count2<<endl;
```

If you run this you will get the same number for both counters.
so the max size of j after the condition is true is i.
and that means that the inner loop will run for O(i) = O(n)

and this leaves us with:

```
O(log(n)) . n^2 . n) = O(log(n) . n^3)
```

Is this correct?

alright, now to the real question, if I try to run this code for multiple values, I get:

```
MAX_SIZE = 1000 , count = 2036  
MAX_SIZE = 10000 , count = 32752  
MAX_SIZE = 100000 , count = 131054  
MAX_SIZE = 1000000 , count = 131054  
MAX_SIZE = 10000000 , count = 131054  
MAX_SIZE = 100000000 , count = 131054  
.
.
.
```

and it goes on like this for the same number after 10000, I just want to know if I am missing something, could it be a O(n) complexity? and why?

Comment: Number of lines is irrelevant; "time complexity" is a measure of *time*.

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in an example? Is the entire code equivalent to "if false: noop"? But that condition is evaluated once. I'd call that O(1)

Comment: I edited the question, I will appreciate if you could help.

Comment: The condition will indeed be `true` for some values of `i` and `j`, therefore it can't be dismissed. The inner loop will sometimes execute.

Comment: Is the goal to estimate the number of times `count` is incremented? Or what's the purpose of the count variable?

Comment: "if the time complexity is considered based on ..." -- neither, but that should be explained in any introductory text on that topic. It's based on operations in an abstract machine. You can not just skip reading this. Generally, code that is not executed doesn't affect the complexity, too.

Comment: It helps to assign values to the variables, and then analyze what the program does. For example, the possible values of `i` are `1,2,4,8...` So let's look at what happens when `i` is 8. The `j` loop is `for (j=1; j<=64;j++)`. Then consider what happens with the `if` statement (keeping in mind that `i=8` and `j` is a number between 1 and 64). **How many times does the `k` loop run, and what are the values of `j` when the `k` loop runs?** Once you've answered that question, then you can determine the complexity.

Comment: `10000 * 10000` is 100 million, which fits into a 32-bit number. `100000 * 100000` is 10 billion, which does *not* fit into a 32-bit number. The 131054 is repeated because at some point `i*i` overflows and becomes negative. The `j` loop doesn't run when `i*i` is negative.

Comment: You are correct that the `if (i%j == 0)` can only be true when `j <= i`.

Comment: @user3386109 thank you that does make sense. So the complexity still nearly O(n^3)?

Comment: The `k` loop is a red herring. It doesn't run often enough to contribute to the time complexity. The two lines of code that run the most are the `j` loop and the `if` statement. For large N, the `j <= i*i` comparison, and the `i%j == 0` comparison are executed `1.33 * N^2` times. For example, with N=256, the `j` loop runs 87381 times, the `i%j==0` condition is checked 87381 times but is true only 45 times, and the `count++` line is executed 1013 times. The number of times `count++` runs is roughly `4 * N`, but the `j` loop runs `1.33 * N^2 times`. So the complexity is O(N^2).

Comment: The question is ambiguous. I think what you're asking is not the time complexity, but rather the (complexity of the) number of times that `count += 1` is executed. Is that right?

Comment: This is my first question here, apologies :)  
I do want the time complexity of the code, but now I am not sure.  
like the *condition* for large numbers barely execute.  
for example: if I have a loop that has a condition like this *if(false) count++;*     
what should the time complexity be since the only condition in the loop will not execute?  
@PaulHankin

Answer (score -2):

1.Outer Loop:
The loop iterates while i is less than or equal to MAX_SIZE, and in each iteration, i is doubled (i *= 2). This is a geometric progression, and the number of iterations will be logarithmic with respect to MAX_SIZE. The time complexity of the outer loop is O(log(MAX_SIZE)).

2.Middle Loop: The middle loop iterates i * i times in each outer loop iteration. Therefore, the time complexity of the middle loop is O(i^2).

3.Innermost Loop: The innermost loop iterates j times in each middle loop iteration. So, the time complexity of the innermost loop is O(j).

Putting it all together, the overall time complexity of the provided code is the product of the time complexities of the three nested loops:

�
(
log
⁡
(
MAX_SIZE
)
⋅
i
2
⋅
j
)
O(log(MAX_SIZE)⋅i
2
⋅j)

Now, it's important to note that the condition i % j == 0 in the middle loop means that the innermost loop only executes when j is a divisor of i. The overall time complexity will be affected by the distribution of divisors in the range of j for different values of i.

In summary, the time complexity is often expressed based on the dominant term, and in this case, the outer loop dominates the overall time complexity, resulting in a final complexity of
�
(
log
⁡
(
MAX_SIZE
)
)
O(log(MAX_SIZE)).